# Unity Rotating GameObject around player in top down 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and my research on this issue isn't getting me any results.

I am trying to get a GameObject rotate around the Player in the direction of the mouse.

[image: Here is my hierarchy]

and the class I have for the RotatePoint

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Launcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera mainCamera;
    private Vector3 mousePos;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        faceMouse();
    }

    private void faceMouse()
    {
        mousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
   Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));

        Vector3 distence = mousePos - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(distence);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, rotation, 1);
    }
}
```

[Player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub7Sr.png)

[Main Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPvMZ.png)

[Rotate Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g05qi.png)

[Projectile Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aZn9.png)

right now it works EXCEPT for its 90 degrees off where it should be.

I watched a few tutorials on this but they all seem to be for 2D which apparently doesn't convert so nicely to 3D

Comment: Can you give some screenshots

Comment: `LookRotation` makes your objects `z` axis align with the given direction ... if it is 90° off it sounds like your `ProjectileTransform` is not offset in Z direction but a different axis -> either fix that local offset itself ... or simply add those 90° to the `rotation` everytime (`rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(distence) * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);` e.g. to add 90° on the X axis)

Comment: The only thing thats offset is the camera on a 90 degree x rotation to get the top down view. Changing the rotation the of RotatePoint GameObject to match that still doesnt work and even adding it in the program isnt helping.

Comment: Could you include the inspector of `Transform` of your objects?

Comment: I added the inspector for all the related objects